# I am getting a RuntimeWarning when trying to make a logarithmic regression curve using curve_fit. I am also getting an optimal parameters not found

Tags: python, numpy, parameters, curve-fitting, logarithm

Hello I am struggling ot make a logarithmic regression for this data here. Whenever I use the timereg array to calculate the regression I get and error that says
'RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log.'
Then it gives this error:
'Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800.'
The worst part is that it works perfectly fine when I use the yearsreg array in place of the timereg array.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
```

```
numevents = np.array([48561, 41991, 50973, 46383, 52007, 48875, 50936, 52956, 52409,
        53976, 59010, 71190, 57398, 62807, 79091, 64503, 59985, 59465,
        57788, 56003, 57025, 62693, 67652, 57001])

#### Creating a new array with the same number of values as there are years in the data in order to 
#### get a proper logarithmic curve from curve_fit.
yearsreg = np.arange(1, 25)
timereg = np.arange(1996, 2020)

#### Creating a new set of years that predicts into the future.
t2060 = np.arange(1, 46)


#### Creating a new array of the years to use as the xticks on the graph.
yearspredict = np.arange(1996, 2041)

#### Creating a Logarithmic Function
def logs(x, a, b, c):
    y = a * np.log(b * x) +c
    return y

#### Using this fucntion in curve_fit.
popt, pcov = curve_fit(logs, timereg, numevents, p0 = (1, 1, 50000))


#### Extracting the curve_fit parameter guesses.
a = popt[0]
b = popt[1]
c = popt[2]


# Finding the curve of the logarithmic regression and using it to predict into the future.
ev_logfit = logs(yearsreg, a, b, c)
w2060 = logs(t2060, a, b, c)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see values in variables - maybe this helps you see when and why there is problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they are two anomalies :

First : They are 25 values of x but only 24 values of y.

Second : This is the main anomaly which is probably the cause of the trouble. The equation

y = a * log(b * x) + c

involves three parameters, but they are not independent parameters. The equation should be writen with only two independent parameters :

y = a * log(x) + C

with C = a * log(b) + c .

Equivalently you could specify b=1 and proceed for the regression for a and c only.